# NSXmlParser with UITableView not loading rows

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, ios4, nsxmlparser

ok so I am trying to parse XML data into a table, this is the code I currently have, it is not showing the name within each row on the table and I think my code is very inefficient because I have read from two different books and tried my best to get everything working together. Please can to suggest code improvements and a fix for my issue thanks :D I am also aware, I havent released anything yet, was going to do that at a later date :)

```
#import "firstLevelViewController.h"
#define INTERESTING_TAG_NAMES @"text", @"name", nil

@implementation firstLevelViewController
@synthesize tweetsData;
@synthesize userArray;
@synthesize tableArray;


-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.userArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    interestingTags = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects: INTERESTING_TAG_NAMES];

    self.title = @"test";

    [tweetsData release];
    tweetsData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init]; //alloc the holder for xml, may be large so we use nsmutabledata type

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.xml"];//url string to download

    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url]; //set a request with the url

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]; //start the connection and call connection methods from below

    [connection release];
    [request release];
}

//called various times
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"didReceieveData Connection");
    [tweetsData appendData:data]; //append data from method call line to tweetsData tweetsData now holds xml file
}


//called after downloaded finished
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"finished");
    [self startParsingTweets];  
}

//*****************************START PARSER CODE************************************

-(void)startParsingTweets
{
    NSLog(@"parsing init");
    NSXMLParser *tweetParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:tweetsData]; //uses the NSMutableData data type to parse
    tweetParser.delegate = self; //set the delegate to this viewControlelr
    [tweetParser parse];
    [tweetParser release];
}

//called when the document is parsed
-(void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    NSLog(@"parsing started");
    [tweetsString release]; //make sure its empty to get rid of any previous data

    tweetsString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:(20 * (140 + 20))]; // ( number of calls * ( size of tweet + username )
    currentElementName = nil;
    currentText = nil;
}

//this is called for each xml element
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"started element");
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"status"]) //if elementName == status then start of new tweet so make new dictionary
    {
        [currentTweetDict release];
        currentTweetDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:[interestingTags count]]; //make dictionary with two sections
    }
    else if([interestingTags containsObject:elementName]) //if current element is one stored in interesting tag, hold onto the elementName and make a new string to hold its value
    {
        currentElementName = elementName; //hold onto current element name
        currentText = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }

}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog(@"appending");
    [currentText appendString:string];
}

//after each element it goes back to the parent after calling this method
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:currentElementName])
    {
        [currentTweetDict setValue: currentText forKey: currentElementName];
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"status"])
    {
        [self.userArray addObject:currentTweetDict];

        //eventually placed in table just testing for now

    }

    [currentText release];
    currentText = nil;
}

-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    for(int i=0;i<[self.userArray count];i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *rowData = [self.userArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *textName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"user: %@", [rowData objectForKey:@"name"]];
        [self.tableArray addObject:textName];
    }

        NSLog(@"done");

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.userArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *FirstLevelIdentifier = @"FirstLevelIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:FirstLevelIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:FirstLevelIdentifier];
    }

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSDictionary *rowData = [self.tableArray objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *textName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"user: %@", [rowData objectForKey:@"name"]];
    cell.textLabel.text = textName;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after your data is ready to be displayed on the table view, you should call `reloadData` to make the `UITableView` delegate methods be called again.

```
-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    for(int i=0;i<[self.userArray count];i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *rowData = [self.userArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *textName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"user: %@", [rowData objectForKey:@"name"]];
        [self.tableArray addObject:textName];
    }

        NSLog(@"done");

     //reloadData so that the table view delegate get called again
     [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

As for the parsing and the async request, it seems you are doing the right way as both `NSURLConnection` and `NSXMLParser` use the delegation pattern to work.

Some thinks some people might say that you could do to improve performance is replacing NSURLConnection for [ASIHttpRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), and may be use other 3rd party XML library to parse  your data faster and easier (here is [a nice article about hot to choose the best xml parser for your app](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project))

Comment: what about adding the data to the table, am i doing it the correct way.

Comment: yes, it seems you are doing the right way in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You are also using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, which is essential for performance. You should only release `textName` after setting the text for your cell, you might have a memory leak there as you alloc the string and never releases it.

Comment: and also set the cell to autorelease when you init it: `[cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:FirstLevelIdentifier] autorelease];`

Comment: yep I have done that already, got an issue tho...when viewing my table I can scroll down without any issues, but if i scroll up again, the app crashes, nothing is reported to the console.

Comment: woops nevermind I fixed it, had [rowData release] in the CellForRowAtIndexPath :D

Comment: at `parserDidEndDocument` you are adding a `NSString` (which is also not release) to `tableArray` and then at your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you are trying to use it as a `NSDictionary`